# Eigenvalues of antidiagonal block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have an anti-diagonal block matrix $$J=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & A \\
B & 0 \end{array} \right)$$

where $A$ is $m\times m$ and $B$ is $n \times n$. Is there a trick to calculating the eigenvalues when $m$ and $n$ are different? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @levap: Here, $A$ and $B$ have different dimensions, while in the other question they have equal dimensions.

Comment: @maugjf, did you come across a solution yet?